# I'm using 5.1.2, and where can I find the details of failed/skipped tests

Tags: sonarqube

Previously we could drill down from the project dashboard into the skipped / failed tests, and we would get the expected and stacktrace. Now with 5.1.2 when clicking for instance on skipped tests we see the file hierarchy, showing the numbers for the files, and when clicking on a file we just get the source. If there are 5 tests in the file, and 1 failed, how to see which one?

Answer (score 0):

You have to click on the left menu icon when you are on a file, and select the "Show details" entry.

This is described on the official SonarQube documentation, more specifically on the ["Component tests" page](http://docs.sonarqube.org/display/SONAR/Component+tests).

Comment: Oops, error in our plugin. Thanks, works very nice indeed.

Comment: It looks like it's only working for Java files and not C# files. Is it correct ?

Comment: It works for language plugins that provide enough information to SonarQube - which is not the case of the C# plugin indeed.

Comment: Thank you @Fabrice-SonarSourceTeam. Maybe one day we'll have access to these informations :-)